# Typescript migration throwing error on Stack.Screen options

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation

I am converting an application from JS into TSX, but I encountered an error that I am not sure how to fix.

This is a function in my Screens.tsx file, and I have similar functions that are stacking other screens.

```
function ElementsStack(props: any) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator mode="card" headerMode="screen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Elements"
        component={Elements}
        options={{
          header: ({ navigation, scene }) => (
            <Header title="Elements" navigation={navigation} scene={scene} />
          ),
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE" },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

The props that I am sending to the Header components (it's a .js file) are throwing me this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

Is there any way I can work around this error? Is that something that I can fix at the Header component level?

Comment: Show the definition of ```Header``` component.

Comment: class Header extends React.Component {
  handleLeftPress = () => {
    const { back, navigation, scene } = this.props;
    return (back ? navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack()) : navigation.openDrawer());
  }


Conversion into FC needed.